# How to store win-loss record with RESTful API and JS?

Tags: ajax, rest, reactjs

I'm making a game using ReactJS. I'm a front-end guy so I got that part down. I'm very new to back-end so I thought I'd get some help about how to GET and POST a player's data (i.e. win/loss record) using RESTful API. 
I'm using Express and ajax.

### Server.js code

```
  app.get('/api/progress', function(req, res) {
  res.send({
    wins: winCount,
    losses: loseCount
 });
 var winCount = 0;
 var loseCount = 0;
});

app.post('/api/progress', function(req, res) {

  res.send(204);

});
```

At the moment, that's all I have for my server. I hard coded some values in there just to see it working.

### JS File ##

```
function endFight() {


  if(state.playerHP < 1) {


    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/progress',
      method: 'POST',

    });

  }

  if(state.cpuHP < 1) {


    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/progress',
      method: 'POST',

     });
   }


 }
```

So I was thinking I'd POST the results after we see if the player lost or won. But I have no idea how to start this.

Sorry if this is so ambiguous. I really don't know what I'm doing so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO :) to help clarify your question, are you asking how to configure the server address in the ReactJS library, so that when your `$.ajax()` functions are reached, the server receives the request?

Comment: Hi Andrew. Sorry, I didn't get any notification that your replied to my question so I didn't see this until now. In any case, I figured out the answer to my question!